# How to keep format of cells while exporting a table into excel

Tags: php, html, excel, format, styles

I have my html table exporting to a new excel file by doing the following:

```
<script>
function s2ab(s) {
    if(typeof ArrayBuffer !== 'undefined') {
        var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
        var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
        for(var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) view[i]=s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
        return buf;
    } else {
        var buf = new Array(s.length);
        for (var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) buf[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
        return buf;
    }
}
function exportTable(id, type, fn) {
    var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(document.getElementById(id), {sheet:"Sheet1"});
    var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType: type, bookSST:true, type: 'binary'});
    var fname = fn || 'FET_Changes.' + type;
    try {
        saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], {type:"application/octet-stream"}), fname);
    } catch(e) { if(typeof console != 'undefined') console.log(e, wbout);}
    return wbout;
}
function doit(type, fn) {return exportTable('Info', type || 'xlsx', fn);}
</script>
```

It exports the text in each cell, but not the highlighting I have formatted like this in php for a certain reason:

`echo'<td class="Test", style="background-color:#FFFF00">'.$info['ColOne'].' </td>'.PHP_EOL;`

Is there a way for me to get the **background-color** to show up in the excel?